# Wifi P2P camera application android

Tags: android, p2p

I have a P2P camera that I need to get the video steam onto a android application that I am creating for my Senior Design Project. The camera is a Q7 Mini WiFi P2P H.264 Network IP Camera 480P (http://www.gearbest.com/ip-cameras/pp_449003.html)

My question, is it possible to get the preview feed onto my android application?

This is a little new to me so I apologize if the details are vague, I really don't know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Each IP Camera should have its rtsp or rtmp streaming URL provided by manufacturer. 
For example: **rtsp://192.168.0.16/camera1**

And there are several RTSP Player examples, using them you can get the camera feed to your application.

If you couldn't find the URL, checkout this link for "How can I find the right RTSP URI for my IP camera?"

http://ipcamlive.com/faqs

Link to download the software.
https://sourceforge.net/projects/onvifdm/